# How to merge two dataset with limited overlap in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I am trying to merge two relatively similair dataset without much success. For me rbind() or left_join() aren't working. My begindatasets are:

A:

```html
ID item1 item2 item3
1 5 0 0
2 0 0 0
3 0 2 0
4 0 0 3
5 0 3 4
6 4 0 0
```

and 
B:

```html
ID item1 item6 item10
7 2 0 0
8 0 0 4
9 2 2 5
10 0 0 3
11 0 3 4
12 1 1 0
```

I want to combine these to result in C:

```html
ID item1 item2 item3 item6 item10
1 5 0 0 NA NA
2 0 0 0 NA NA
3 0 2 0 NA NA
4 0 0 3 NA NA
5 0 3 4 NA NA
6 4 0 0 NA NA
7 2 NA NA 0 0
8 0 NA NA 0 4
9 2 NA NA 2 5
10 0 NA NA 0 3
11 0 NA NA 3 4
12 1 NA NA 1 0
```

Comment: `merge(A, B, all = TRUE)`

Comment: You can add empty item6 and item10 columns to data frame A and empty item1 item2 item3 columns to data frame B and then do rbind

Comment: Hi Ronak, with a simple merge I get item1 twice in the dataset, once "item1" and one "item1.x". I need to merge those into 1 column to avoid duplicates. Not manually, but in a scalable manner. In that sence my question is a little different then the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: dplyr::bind_rows(A,B)